# I get Network is unreachable in Java

Tags: linux, networking, packet, dhcp

Good day everyone!

I am making a DHCP Server for a project. I tried it in Windows and it worked. Now, I need to make it work on Linux. I used the same code and it can listen packets coming from port 67. However, every time I am about to send packets to the machine in KVM (Kernel Virtual Machine), I get an error at line containing "datagramsocket.send(response)" saying that Network is Unreachable. Btw, I am using a centOS as host and another centOS as guest machine. Bridge connection and firewall is disabled. How could I fix this problem? I am clueless.

Thanks in advance! :)

I used a dhcp4java API and here's a portion of my code:

```
    if (replypacket != null){
       InetAddress add = replypacket.getAddress();
       int port = replypacket.getPort();
       byte[] buf = replypacket.serialize();
       DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, add, port);
       datagramsocket.send(response);
    }
```

Comment: Give us information, we're not mind readers. Which are the ip addresses of the host and the VM? How do you open the socket, listen for a connection, and send the result? Post your code please.

Comment: we're not going to steal your code :)

Comment: Hi, I edited the post and included the code :)